# Как обрабатывать событие добавления элемента в панель?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Делаю свою панель. Мне нужно обрабатывать событие добавления элемента. Если элемент первый, то он должен расположиться по центру. Проблема в том в момент добавления элемента `this.ActualWidth` и `this.ActualHeight` равны `0`, но мне ж нужно как-то высчитать центр панели чтобы расположить элемент. Подскажите что я неверно делаю?

```
     public class MyPanel : Panel
      {
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            Size size = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
            foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
                element.Measure(size);
            return new Size();
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
            {
                double x = 0;
                double y = 0;
                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(element);
                if (!Double.IsNaN(left))
                    x = left;
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(element);
                if (!Double.IsNaN(top))
                    y = top;
                element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), element.DesiredSize));
            }

            return finalSize;
        }
            protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
            {
                if (visualAdded != null)
                {
                    if (this.Children.Count == 1)
                    {                   
                        var control = visualAdded as FrameworkElement;
                        if (control != null)
                        {
                            double x = this.ActualWidth / 2 - control.ActualWidth / 2;
                            double y = this.ActualHeight / 2 - control.ActualHeight / 2;
                            control.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x,y), control.DesiredSize));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (visualRemoved != null)
                {
                    // Do stuff with the removed object
                }

                base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вам нужно по идее перегрузить MeasureOverride и ArrangeOverride, а OnVisualChildrenChanged может быть и вовсе не нужно.

Comment: @VladD, Я совсем не понимаю как их нужно использовать. И как тогда обрабатывать добавление нового контрола?

Comment: По идее, они автоматически должны вызываться при добавлении контрола.

Comment: У вас MeasureOverride неправильный, он говорит, что размер у вас нулевой. Вот вам и дают 0 места.

Comment: @VladD, Да, так и происходит, они вызываются сразу после добавления новго контрола. Но как мне в `ArrangeOverride` отследить какой контрол был добавлен последним?

Comment: Я попробую написать, как доберусь до компа.

Comment: @VladD, Окей, буду ждать.

Comment: Окей, а разве последний добавленный элемент не будет последним в InternalChildren?

Comment: И ещё вопрос, а как должны располагаться остальные элементы? Если их два? Три?

Comment: @VladD, Вообще эта панель планируется использовать только для Dragndrop операций. Если перетягивают первый элемент, то он становится по центру, все остальные будут прижиматься к ближайшему к ним элементу.

Comment: Ну окей, а в каком порядке будут элементы, если их 5? Зависит от того, _куда_ дропнули, или просто фиксированный порядок.

Comment: @VladD, В зависимости куда их дропнули, элемент должен найти ближайшего к себе и прижаться к нему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой вариант, от которого можно начинать работу:

```
class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var childAvailableSize = new Size(availableSize.Width, double.PositiveInfinity);
        Size desiredSize = new Size();

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            if (child == null)
                continue;
            child.Measure(childAvailableSize);
            Size childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;
            desiredSize.Width = Math.Max(desiredSize.Width, childDesiredSize.Width);
            desiredSize.Height += childDesiredSize.Height;
        }

        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        bool first = true;
        bool addAbove = false;
        double MinH = finalSize.Height / 2, MaxH = MinH;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            if (child == null)
                continue;
            var childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;
            Point childPos;
            if (first)
            {
                double halfHeight = childDesiredSize.Height / 2;
                childPos = new Point(0, MinH - halfHeight);
                MinH -= halfHeight;
                MaxH += halfHeight;
            }
            else if (addAbove)
            {
                childPos = new Point(0, MinH - childDesiredSize.Height);
                MinH -= childDesiredSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                childPos = new Point(0, MaxH);
                MaxH += childDesiredSize.Height;
            }
            Rect childRect = new Rect(childPos, childDesiredSize);
            child.Arrange(childRect);
            addAbove = !addAbove;
            first = false;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

С вот таким XAML'ом:

```
<local:MyPanel Background="Ivory" Height="300">
    <Border Height="30" Width="30" Background="Yellow"/>
    <Border Height="40" Width="40" Background="DarkGreen"/>
    <Border Height="50" Width="200" Background="BlueViolet"/>
    <Border Height="40" Width="10" Background="Red"/>
    <Border Height="20" Width="80" Background="DarkGray"/>
</local:MyPanel>
```

выдаёт такую картинку:

[image: гистограмма!]

Вам нужно ещё задать порядок на child-элементах (судя по всему, лучше через attached property, как `Grid`), и сортировать по нему.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.