# Расположить блоки плитками - WPF, XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте,
Только начал работать с WPF и ответ на свой вопрос в Гугле не нашел, так что прошу, камнями не кидать.
Значит так, распологаю блоки в WrapPanel, что-бы выстраивались нужным образом после изменения размеров окна:

```
   <WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <WrapPanel>
                <GroupBox Header="Block1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="50" Background="Gray"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Block2">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="150" Background="LightBlue"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Block3">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="25" Background="LightCoral"/>
                </GroupBox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Если окно нормального размера, то блоки выстраиваются как и надо:
[image: Окно, нормальное состояние]

Если же, это окно увеличить, то получается вот такое вот:
[image: Окно, увеличенное состояние, не правильный вид]

А надо вот так:

[image: Окно, увеличенное состояние, нужное отображение]

Что можно сделать? В какую сторону копать?
Спасибо большое!

UPDATE:

Нашел вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158561/how-to-appose-wrappanel-items-of-different-heights-vertically, но там используется чья-то библиотека. Неужели стандартно такого сделать нельзя?

Comment: Наверное в сторону Grid и кода, который при изменении размеров окна зная размеры элементов будет перекладывать их как надо.

Comment: В принципе, очень просто самому написать нужный контейнер вручную. Если не забуду, напишу пример на следующей неделе. Вот из существущего: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549816/10105.

Answer (score 1):

Да, как правильно написано по вашей ссылке в стандартном `WPF` такой возможности нет. К сожалению. Но нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы использовать библиотеки от других разработчиков!

Т.к. на данный момент нет NuGet - пакета (Вы можете предложить сделать это в issue на github :)) то вам нужно будет скачать исходники и собрать .dll самостоятельно.

Добавлю пример под ваш код:

```
<Masonry:MasonryControl>
    <GroupBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Header="Block1">
        <StackPanel Width="200"
                    Height="50"
                    Background="Gray" />
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Block2">
        <StackPanel Width="200"
                    Height="150"
                    Background="LightBlue" />
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Block3">
        <StackPanel Width="200"
                    Height="25"
                    Background="LightCoral" />
    </GroupBox>
</Masonry:MasonryControl>
```

Отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [nblz.ru](http://0s.ne.on2gcy3l.nfwwo5lsfzrw63i.nblz.ru/VYQKC.jpg))</sub>